# Is there a smart possibility to get API results without sending requests every second? [VueJS | Vuetify]

Tags: vue.js, rest, vuetify.js

I made a web site to show which services on my server are running and which are offline.
The site is an Vuetify App running in a docker container. My services are monitored via UptimeRobot.

Currently I use:

```
    created: function () {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getStatuses(), 1000);
    },
```

To trigger my API request function every second to update the status of my services.
But is there some smarter possibility to only update on change and not request every second to see if something happened?

Like I send one request to get the status and then receive a message when something changed? I hope you can understand, whats my problem. It's hard to describe.

Comment: Look into websockets. You might also consider just polling less frequently - perhaps you could only do it once a minute. If your services are failing frequently enough for that not to be sufficient, you should probably spend your time fixing the underlying issues.

Comment: Good point. I could definitely change it to one minute. But if websockets do what I want, I will have a look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by firing an event. for example:

in your **app.js**

```
window.Fire = new Vue();
```

For example here you create a user then you want to update table after creating a new user, Follow these steps:

```
createUser(){

 // FireUpdate is your fire name, you can give it any name you want!
 // Call this after you post something to specific route.

 Fire.$emit('FireUpadte'); 
}
```

Then you will load new users using this approach:

```
created(){
  // Load new Users after created.

  Fire.$on('FireUpadte', () => { this.createUser(); });
}
```

For more information check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHuTkJzH2jI&list=PLB4AdipoHpxaHDLIaMdtro1eXnQtl_UvE&index=20

Comment: They are trying to update from an api on their backend.  This is helpful for triggering updates from one front end component to another.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are `websockets`.  You establish a websocket connection and it stays open, allowing the server to notify the web app when something changes.

You can run your own `socket.io` server on a `Node.js` backend or use a service like `Pusher.com` (very cheap, free tier is pretty big).

I highly recommend going the `Pusher.com` route, they also have great tutorials ; )

https://pusher.com